# Using FB login with Libspotify/Hallon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, spotify

I'm working on my first rails app and am trying to make it so that Users can create a joint Playlist and then play that playlist. I planned on using Hallon/Libspotify to create the playlist but am running into a problem because Spotify requires users to login with FB.

I currently have it set so that Users login to the site using Facebook but I don't think the information FB gives me is enough to auto log the User into Spotify. Any suggestions on how to implement this functionality would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a Facebook auth token with libspotify.

libspotify requires a username and password pair, whether it's a Spotify name/password or a Facebook name/password. Once you log in with libspotify, you'll be given a separate login auth token for storing and future logins.

It's important to abide by the libspotify ToS when writing your app, as it's easy to break them when writing a web app. The two most important are:

- Never store a username/password yourself. Only ever store the token you get (it's safe to store unencrypted).
- Never log in on behalf of the user when they're not using your application.

Comment: Ok so, if I understand correctly, it would be better to use "login with Spotify" instead of "login with FB" so that I have a Spotify token instead of a FB token. I can then use the Spotify token to do things with libspotify?

I'm currently using OmniAuth, is there any Spotify auth file already or do I need to do that from scratch? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: libspotify auth tokens are completely separate from Facebook auth tokens — if your app uses Facebook integration, the user will need to log in twice, once to Facebook and once to libspotify. That the user logs into libspotify with Facebook credentials is an implementation detail.